# getting org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Oct 29, 2015 2:29:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/globeconnect] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.globetouch.business.entities.DummyData] with root cause
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.globetouch.business.entities.DummyData

@Entity
@Table(name="DUMMY_DATA")
public class DummyData {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ICCID")
    private String ICCID;
    @Column(name="IMSI")
    private String IMSI;



create table DUMMY_DATA(
   ICCID VARCHAR(255),
   IMSI  VARCHAR(255),
   PRIMARY KEY (ICCID)
);
```

I am getting the following exception. i am reading the content from the file and saving in the data base. ICCID value will be given from file. Actually I am setting the file content value to ICCID,can u help me out with where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Stacktrace is pretty obvious. Either you have to manually set ids or add `@GeneratedValue` annotation above your `ICCID` something like this:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "yourSEQ", sequenceName = "your_id_seq")
@Id
@Column(name = "ICCID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "yourSEQ")
private String ICCID;
```

Of course you have to create `your_id_seq` sequence on database.